# Perflib, PerfNet, usbperf and iisinfoctrs errors in windows server 2012 running Sharepoint 2016

Tags: internal-server-error

I am having the following error in my sharepoint 2016 server:

Below are the event ids seen in event viewer:

> Event ID: 1008 The Open Procedure for service "BITS" in DLL
>   "C:\Windows\System32\bitsperf.dll" failed. Performance data for this
>   service will not be available. The first four bytes (DWORD) of the
>   Data section contains the error code.
>
> Event ID: 1001 Unable to read the first counter index value from the
>   registry.  The error code returned by the registry is data DWORD 0.

E

> vent ID: 2004 Unable to open the Server service performance object.
>   The first four bytes (DWORD) of the Data section contains the status
>   code.
>
> Event ID: 2001 Unable to read the "First Counter" value under the
>   usbperf\Performance Key. Status codes returned in data.
>
> Event ID: 2002 Setting up Web Service counters failed, please make
>   sure your Web Service counters are registered correctly.

I have tried the following resolutions till now:

1. Rebuilding the counters:
    cd c:\windows\system32
    lodctr /R
    cd c:\windows\sysWOW64
    lodctr /R

Resyncing the counters with Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI):
     WINMGMT.EXE /RESYNCPERF

Stop and restart the Performance Logs and Alerts service. 
Stop and restart the Windows Management Instrumentation service.

2. cd c:\Windows\Inf\W3SVC lodctr .409\w3ctrs.ini

This seem to have worked to fix Event ID: 2002

3. cd c:\Windows\Inf\inetinfo lodctr .409\infoctrs.ini

   Throws error: Unable to find initialization file .409\infoctrs.ini

cd c:\Windows\Inf\usbhub lodctr .409\usbperf.ini

Throws error: Unable to find initialization file .409\usbperf.ini